# faster tab delimited import of large file access vba

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, import

I have a .tab file which is 176mb with 780k records which I have to load to Access every day and delete old data. I also want to have ImportDate in the same table.

I've tried different methods of importing and it's been really slow. With DAO it took about 14 minutes to import and insert date. I tried with DoCmd but it took just as slow, if not more. I can't delete the table but need to insert into it because access does not set the properties for the fields accurately. I also figured out that I need to compact database every time or it's getting big.

What can I do to import the file faster? Doing it manually doesn't take that long.

Here is what I've tried:

```
compactfile = accdbfilepath
srcfile = "filepath\filename2017_be.accdb"
moaqdate = "8/22/2017"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CopyFile srcfile, compactfile
Set db = OpenDatabase(compactfile)
db.Execute "DELETE * FROM [MOAQ]"
db.Execute ("insert INTO [MOAQ] select * FROM 
[Text;HDR=YES,FMT=TabDelimited;Database=" & accesspath & "].[" & 
filenametotab & "]"), dbFailOnError
db.Execute "update [MOAQ] set importdate =(""" & moaqdate & """)"
db.Close

destinationfile = "filepath\filename2017_be.accdb"
Application.CompactRepair compactfile, destinationfile


fso.CopyFile destinationfile, srcfile
Kill destinationfile
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: I'd say unless you are going to consider switching to SQL Server or SQL Server Express, you probably don't have many options other than to get a coffee whilst you wait.  If you were using SQL Server you could use Bulk Insert which is very fast.

Comment: What other methods have you tried? There is `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` and `DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport`, the latter should be equivalent to doing the import manually.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
compactfile = accdbfilepath
srcfile = "filepath\empty_MOAQ_table_only_be.accdb"
destinationfile = "filepath\MOAQ_table_be.accdb"
moaqdate = "8/22/2017"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.CopyFile srcfile, destinationfile, True
Set db = OpenDatabase(destinationfile)
db.Execute ("insert INTO [MOAQ] select #" & moaqdate & "# as importdate, * " & _
    "FROM [Text;HDR=YES,FMT=TabDelimited;Database=" & accesspath & "].[" & filenametotab & "]"), dbFailOnError
db.Close
Set FSO = Nothing
```

In this case you won't need to copy file with data twice, delete the data, do compact & repair and update the date.

Separate your big table into dedicated backend with just one table, create a copy of this file with empty table (empty_MOAQ_table_only_be.accdb) and copy it over existing dedicated backend instead of double coping big files, deleting and c&r.

You can insert update date at the same time with file data, no need to update.

It should work much faster.

Comment: i tried this code but i am getting error 128 and vba simply skips the line of import

Comment: compactfile = "filepath\Backend\MOAQ2017_be.accdb"
moaqdate = "8/22/2017"
On Error Resume Next
'removing older tab files
accesspath = "filepath\Backend\"
filenametotab = "MOAQ_2017_REPORT_20170725.txt"
Strfilename = accesspath & filenametotab


Set db = OpenDatabase(compactfile)
db.Execute "DELETE * FROM [MOAQ]"


db.Execute ("insert INTO [MOAQ] select #" & moaqdate & "# as importdate, * " & _
    "FROM [Text;HDR=YES,FMT=TabDelimited;Database=" & accesspath & "].[" & filenametotab & "]"), dbFailOnError
db.Close

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`, provide full text of error. Looks like text file has invalid column names. Also there may be a problem with SQL text. Dump SQL text to Immediate window using Debug.Pring and try to "run" it query builder